# How to open Popup through kv?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

It should be very easy, but I could not find the answer. I need to open `Popup`with button through `.kv` file. Less words, more code!

```
#.kv
#...
Button:
    on_press:
        #Here I need something like
        #Popup_open: 
            #title: 'title'
            #...
```

I know I can do it by adding function to my root class

```
#main.py
#...
myclass(object):
    def myPopup():
        Popup(title='title',message='message').open()
```

and then call this function

```
#.kv
#...
Button:
    on_press: root.myPopup()
```

but it's not the most convenient way for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two rules:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<YourPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'something'
    Label:
        text: 'content'
<Test>:
    Button:
        on_press: Factory.YourPopup().open()
```

Comment: I felt in another trouble using this `Popup`. It should display warning and Two buttons `Yes and No` (everything okay at this point) I have function in my main class in `main.py` and need to call this function when `Yes` is pressed. Also I need to pass text from `TextInput` as parameter to this function. I tried using `#:set Answer True` if `Yes` is pressed, but it didn't work. Also I tried using `global` in my `.kv` file, but no result. I can create question if it would be more convenient

Comment: Ah, I just understood. I can place this function to my main (App)class and call it with `app.myfunc()`, right? But how to insert parameter?